# CSS / HTML - column width formatting

Tags: html, css

I have two pieces of code.  I was expecting these to have the same result, but no luck.  Can someone explain this to me?

```
<table border=1px>
  <tr>
    <td width=20%>test1</td>
    <td width=80%>test2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<style>
    table { width:100%;}
    td.1  { width:20%; }
    td.2  { width:80%; }
</style>
```

This works as I expect.  The first column is 20%, the second is 80%.

```
<table border=1px>
  <tr>
    <td class="1">test1</td>
    <td class="2">test2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<style>
  table { width:100%;}
  td.1  { width:20%; }
  td.2  { width:80%; }
</style>
```

This version shows column as 50/50.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the numbers `1` and `2` to more appropriate names. CSS names cannot begin with numbers.

```
<table border=1px>
  <tr>
    <td class="twenty-percent-width">test1</td>
    <td class="eighty-percent-width">test2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<style>
  table { width:100%;}
  td.twenty-percent-width  { width:20%; }
  td.eighty-percent-width  { width:80%; }
</style>
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors).

And for good programming practices you should never name variables, names, etc starting with a number

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'm such a noob :)

Comment: No worries! That's why you're here, right? :-) We're glad to help.